# how to open only one file from the listview in android

Tags: android

I am having a list view which will display list of files. When I click on a file it will open in the adobe reader. The problem is when I select the first file and by mistakenly if i click on the second file before the first file got opened in the adobe reader, both the first and second files are getting loaded and are getting opened. first file will be getting opened and when i click on the back button the second file will be loading and it will get opened.
I want to open only first selected file. I dont want other files to get opened when by chance I select another file from list.
How can I do it?

Here is my code

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                    openFile(fileName);


            }
        });
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void openFile(final String fileName) {
        // To Open the file in the default viewer of the device

          File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
         .getAbsolutePath() + "/Drive/" + fileName); 
          Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
          target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf"); 
         target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

         Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open pdf File"); 
         try {

         startActivity(intent); 
         }
         catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
         { 
}
}
```

Comment: post your some snippets here,we try to verify .

Comment: I have added my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a condition in your `public Object getItem(int i)` implementation of your adapter, as its the method used when you click an item.
How do you open the file? In that particular method, raise some sort of flag that you finished your earlier tasks, and check that flag from within `getItem`

There are many mechanisms to do that, without code, its harder to give the proper one.

Comment: Is there a chance that `startActivityForResult(..)` will fit better to your needs?

Answer (score 0):

choose the position based open the file. use like this:May help you.

```
if(position == 0)
     openFile(fileName1);
elseif(position == 1)
      openFile(fileName2);
```

Comment: let me inform me ,you get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From UX point of view if you are mistakenly click on the listview item app should show the bounded data. As a user and a developer I discourage everyone who breaks this pattern.

I understand your concerns and can give you option to improve app behaviour. You can reuse an activity which opens a pdf file so no need to press back button twice.

It can be achieved by using special flag in your itent `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`